# Sharepoint Designer 2007: Reformat HTML removes special characters

Tags: 2007

Everytime I run the Reformat HTML it substitutes the HTML entity name for the special character.

For Example:
I have in HTML ***`&oacute;`*** after I run Reformat HTML... it changes it to ***`ó`***, thus displaying strange characters in some browsers such as Mozilla.
Again, this is in the HTML source screen.

Is it possible to stop this behaviour, or format the source in such a way that it survives the reformatting?

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: what happens if you encode the &: &amp;oacute;

Comment: That is the problem, djeeg. If I enter the HTML entity for ampersand as &amp;, after the Reformat HTML routine is run, it converts it to the character for ampersand (&). I do not want that.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you need to double escape special characters. In your case `&oacute;` should be escaped and entered as `&amp;oacute;`.
What I don't understand here is why different browsers have different behaviors...

Comment: That doesn't change the HTML entity when I run the Reformat HTML routine, so technically it works, BUT it displays &oacute;